# TouchableHighlight doesn't cover whole (Card) Component

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

TouchableHighlight doesn't seem to cover the whole (Card) component i'm using.

It only seems to trigger when I click near or on  in the component.

It doesn't work when I for example click in the middle of my Card component where no text is located.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iN9NF.jpg

Photo where I show what area doesn't trigger the onPress. (Not enough reputation to post images)

```
<View>
        <TouchableHighlight
          onPress={() => this.viewDetail(this.props.uid)}
          underlayColor={Colors.clear}
        >
          <Card key={String(this.props.id)} containerStyle={styles.card}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row" }}>
              <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{String(this.props.title)}</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={{ flex: 0.5 }}>
                <Text style={styles.price}>€{String(this.props.price)}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row", marginTop: 15 }}>
              <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <Text style={styles.address}>
                  <Ionicons name="ios-pin" style={styles.icon} />

                  {/* String(
                  " " +
                    this.props.zipcode +
                    " " +
                    this.props.city +
                    ", " +
                    this.props.streetName +
                    " " +
                    this.props.streetNumber
                ) */

                  String(" " + this.props.zipcode + " " + this.props.city)}
                </Text>
              </View>
              <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <Text style={styles.date}>
                  <Ionicons name="ios-time" style={styles.icon} />

                  {String(" " + this.props.date /* .toLocaleDateString() */)}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </Card>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
```

I expect to click on any place on the Comonent that is wrapped by the TouchableHighlet to trigger it's onPress.

Actual result: "Blind spots" in the middle that doesn't trigger the onPress.

Comment: Try removing the `View` outside `TouchableHighlight` and adding it inside `TouchableHighlight`

Comment: I have tried this and it's still the same.